# Invitation by a retired US citizen

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, invitation-letters

Can a friend who is a USA citizen but has retired from work invite a friend living in Africa to visit him? Is it possible the visitor will be given a visa?

Comment: There is no correlation between an invitation letter and being granted a visa.

Comment: "Africa" is a pretty large and diverse place.

Comment: Yes, people from every African state get US visas. It's not possible to say what your "chances" are without knowing your circumstances though.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it.

Some countries have a formal invitation process where the inviter guarantees to cover the costs of returning an errant visitor home. Some countries insist on invitation letters as essentially a bureaucratic formality. As far as I can tell, the US does neither of these.

An invitation letter can be evidence that the visitor will be supported during their visit, but that is only part of getting a visa. Equally important is convincing the authorities that they will return home rather than becoming an illegal immigrant and an invitation letter really can't help with that.

Ultimately whether or not they get a visa is going to depend largely on their personal and financial circumstances back home.